# JSTL - using variables in an xpath?

Tags: xml, jsp, xslt, jstl

Here is what I would like to do:

```
<x:forEach var="node" select="$doc//*[name()='item']">
    <x:out select="*[name()='${nodeName}']" />
</x:forEach>
```

I want to select an XML node based on the variable `nodeName`.

The above code does not work. The only solution I can come up with goes like this:

```
<x:forEach var="node" select="$doc//*[name()='item']/*">
    <c:set var="nameTest"><x:out select="name($node)" /></c:set>
    <c:if test="${nameTest == nodeName}>
        <x:out select="$node" />
    </c:if>
</x:forEach>
```

Which is not an elegant solution and actually makes me kind of angry to look at.

Anyone have any better ideas please?

And for extra fun times I am stuck using JSTL 1.0

Comment: This code isn't XSLT at all. Why have you tagged the question as "xslt"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the answer:

> Using JSTL Data as XPath Variables
>
> Scoped variables can be used in XPath expressions ($implicitObject:variableName) similar to how they are used in EL (${implicitObject.variableName}). If the implicit object is omitted, scopes will be searched in standard order. Note that the “.” and “[]” notations cannot be used for accessing bean properties.

from the [JSTL Quick Reference Sheet](http://www.cs.uiowa.edu/~slonnegr/wpj/jqr.pdf) (pdf)

So my code becomes:

```
<x:set var="theNode" select="*[name()=$pageScope:nodeName]" />
<x:out select="$theNode" />
```

Answer (score 0):

XSLT has parameters on its own, maybe that could help you. I've found an example here http://www.roseindia.net/jstl/param-xml-jstl-tag.shtml

I'll try to apply the concept to your example

```
...
<x:forEach select="$doc//*[name()='item']">
  <x:out select="*[name()='$nodeName']" />
</x:forEach>
...
```

And then when invoking:

```
<x:transform xml="your.xml" xslt="your.xsl">
  <x:param name="nodeName" value="${nodeName}" />
</x:transform>
```

I haven't tried it, I don't have the tools nearby. And I don't have your full code neither :)

Good luck.