# c:set is not working in JSTL 1.2

Tags: xml, jstl

I am making a dynamic menu base on an xml. This XML will be parsed and build the final menu.
The xml is:

```
<menus>
    <menu>
        <name>menu.level1.Home</name>
        <action>transfer-to-account-input</action>
    </menu>
    <menu>
        <name>menu.level1.Accounts</name>
        <action>accounts-summary</action>
    </menu>
</menus>
```

I used jstl to parse the XML. the x:set seems not working!

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="x" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/xml"%>

<x:forEach select="$docRoot/menus/menu" var="menuvar">
    <x:set select="$menuvar/name" var="menuName1" >
    <c:set var="menuName2">
        <x:out select="$menuvar/name" />
    </c:set>
    ${menuName1} //This doesn't show any thing
    ${menuName2} //This works!
</x:forEach>
```

Am I making a mistake or this is a bug in JSTL 1.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax of `x:set` is referencing `$menuVar` using the XPath variable syntax, but `menuVar` is a JSTL variable. It should be:

```
<x:set select="$pageScope:menuvar/name" var="menuName1" >
```

> Using JSTL Data as XPath Variables
>     Scoped variables can be used in XPath expressions ($implicitObject:variableName) similar to how they are used in EL (${implicitObject.variableName}). If the implicit object is omitted, scopes will be searched in standard order. Note that the “.” and “[]” notations cannot be used for accessing bean properties.

**References**

- [JSTL XML Set Tag](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jstl_xml_set_tag.htm)
- [JSTL - using variables in an xpath?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6700344/1113772)