# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.xpath.VariableStack when use jstl xml

Tags: java, xml, jsp, xpath, jstl

I have some code here.

```
<c:set var="songId" value="${param.songid}"/>
<c:import var="xml" url="WEB-INF/comment.xml" />
<x:parse var="doc" doc="${xml}" scope="session" />
<c:catch var="ex">
<x:forEach var="cmt" select="$doc//*[songId=$songId]" varStatus="counter">
    <li>
        <div class="avacmtSide">
        </div>
        <div class="ctcmtSide">
            <a href="#" style="padding:10px;"><x:out select="$cmt/uploader"/> </a>
            <div style="padding:10px;"><x:out select="$cmt/comment"/> </div>
        </div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
    </li>
</x:forEach>
```

When I run it there is a error java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.xpath.VariableStack. 
When I search google for this error. People said there is missing xalan library. But I have added xalan-2.7.0.jar in my project and it doesn't work. Anyone who know it please help me. Thanks.

Comment: You are running via command line or some IDE e.g. eclipse?

Comment: I running in NetBeans IDE

Comment: Did u add xalan library to your project build path?

Comment: I did add xalan library in my project. It is xalan-2.7.0 but it does'nt work. It is very strange because I used to do it in another project and it work well and i don't know why :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The variable syntax is incorrect:

```
 [songId=$songId]
```

It should be this:

```
 "$doc//*[@songId=${pageScope:songId}]"
```

> Using JSTL Data as XPath Variables
>
> Scoped variables can be used in XPath expressions ($implicitObject:variableName) similar to how they are used in EL (${implicitObject.variableName}). If the implicit object is omitted, scopes will be searched in standard order. Note that the “.” and “[]” notations cannot be used for accessing bean properties.

**References**

- [XPath: Variable Reference](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#NT-VariableReference)
- [JSTL - using variables in an xpath?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6700344/1113772)
- [JSTL Quick Reference](http://www.slideshare.net/Hicham_Qaissi/jstlquick-reference)